# Proof that the phase of the average of unitary complex numbers is the average phase

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, average

I'm quite struggling with the following problem:

-Prove that if
\begin{equation}
re^{i\psi} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=1}^N e^{i\theta_{j}},
\end{equation}

then $\psi = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=1}^N \theta_{j}$, i.e the phase of the average of unitary complex numbers is the average phase

I managed to prove it for N=2, but I need a proof for arbitrary N.

Comment: this is incorrect for $N \ge 3$ unless you have some other conditions as $1+1-1=1$ so for $\theta_1=\theta_2=0, \theta_3=\pi$ the average has phase $0$ while the phase average is $\pi/3$

Comment: Isn't your issue with a product instead of a summation ?

Comment: No, unfortunately it's a summation.That $\psi$ should be the the common average phase to which Kuramoto oscillators synchronize. So if the proposition above is not correct, I have to assume that the whole paper I'm reading is incorrect

Comment: May we see the paper?

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/46776356_The_Kuramoto_model_A_simple_paradigm_for_synchronization_phenomena

Comment: It's equation (2) at pag 140. Anyway, since anyone who talks about Kuramoto oscillators call $\psi$ the "average phase", maybe I'm the one who's missing something

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of rumination, I've come up with a possible answer.

If the phases $\theta_j$ are clustered near each other, we could take the paraxial approximations

\begin{equation}
\psi - \theta_i = arctg\left[\frac{\sum_{j=1}^Nsin(\theta_j-\theta_i)}{\sum_{j=1}^Ncos(\theta_j-\theta_i)}\right] \approx arctg\left[\frac{\sum_{j=1}^N(\theta_j-\theta_i)}{N}\right] \approx \frac{\sum_{j=1}^N(\theta_j-\theta_i)}{N},
\end{equation}
so that
\begin{equation}
\psi \approx \frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=1}^N\theta_j,
\end{equation}
which could be the reason why $\psi$ is usually taken as a measure for the average phase. If that is the case, this estimate should be considered only for quasi-coherent states.